# DMS replication instance connect to RDS failed but EC2 instance in same AZ could work

Tags: amazon-web-services, connection, odbc, amazon-rds, dms

[My topology as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO2AQ.png)

The DMS replication instance connect to the RDS instance in different VPC failed but when I troubleshoot the issue by **creating an EC2 in the same subnet with the DMS replication instance I could telnet, nslookup , psql connect to the RDS instance successfully**...really confusing...

The error messages when DMS instance connects to RDS instance in different VPC:

````
Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Cannot connect to ODBC provider  Network error has occurred, Application-Detailed-Message: RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: 08001 NativeError: 101 Message: [unixODBC]could not connect to server: No route to host  Is the server running on host "pgdb.cf1p5lx4ynpa.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com" (192.168.0.131) and accepting  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?   ODBC general error. Cannot connect to ODBC provider  Network error has occurred RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: 08001 NativeError: 101 Message: [unixODBC]could not connect to server: No route to host  Is the server running on host "pgdb.cf1p5lx4ynpa.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com" (192.168.0.131) and accepting  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?   ODBC general error. Cannot connect to ODBC provider  Network error has occurred RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: 08001 NativeError: 101 Message: [unixODBC]could not connect to server: No route to host  Is the server running on host "pgdb.cf1p5lx4ynpa.us-west ```
````

Answer (score 1):

This is because DMS reserves the 192.168.0.0/24 range.

See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Troubleshooting.html#CHAP_Troubleshooting.General.ReservedIP

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I spent so much time troubleshooting the same issue. This saved me.